# Chrome CSS ignored for dynamic content

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a problem with my css.
I tested it with both latest FF and IE without problem but Chrome does not render it properly.

I want to display all childs elements of a tag as blocks i use

```
Tag > * {
    display:block;
}
```

it works fine in both IE and FF  but not chrome.
I tried forcing it using the console and put display:block but it failed.
It seems as if chrome ignores display:block ?

EDIT: Tag is a custom Tag actually CurrentWeather

full Css :

```
CurrentWeather > * {
    display:block;
}

body {
    text-align:center;
  }


div#result{
    text-align:left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:50%;
}
```

EDIT2:

I think it is an ajax problem as when i harcode the added html it works fine.
Does chrome not apply css on dynamic content ?

thanks

Comment: What is `Tag`? Please show your real code.

Comment: Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HpUgT/1/) in Chrome.. It appears to be working properly for me. Can you post more about your problem, perhaps the solution isn't to make your elements to `display:block` but something else

Comment: Works for me too, see http://jsfiddle.net/bBgbj/1/ in chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector `tag > *` doesn't target all children of a tag, only the immedate children.

You would use `tag *` if you want to target *all* children.

Chrome doesn't have such a serious bug as ignoring `display:block`, so there has to be something that is specific to your case.

It's hard to tell exactly what it is without seeing the code, but some possible reasons:

- The tag is an inline tag, and you are not using a HTML5 doctype.
- The markup is broken, so the child elements are not the elements that you think they are. (Especially as different behaviour between browsers is typical for broken markup.)

Comment: it is a custom tag not and if i use the chrom console to add the display:block statement it does nothing

Comment: @maazza: Perhaps the problem is in what you expect to happen when you make the elements block elements. I see that you use `text-align:center;` on the body element, which is incorrectly handled by IE in that it applies it to block elements also, not only inline elements.

Comment: i dont have problems with IE and FF, as stated above i think my problem is ajax related as when i put static content it works fine (using a copy paste af the dynamic content)

Comment: @maazza: CSS is applied to all content in the page whether it comes from the original page or is added dynamically. If there is a difference between static and dynamic content, then the difference is in the actual content, as CSS is applied the same way in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

works fine for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalBiscuits/nkymw/1/

There may be an error somewhere in your css that's causing Chrome to stop processing the CSS.
If you have a missing `;` or `}` chrome doesn't like this.

You'll need to show us all your code or else use the CSS validator to look over your code
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/